# Lenovo T14 AMD microphone/output device gives weird echoing/crackling noises

Tags: 20.04, sound, lenovo, speakers

this is my first question so please be kind regarding any mistakes, etc.

So, I've got a problem with my lenovo t14 amd laptop. From time to time, the output device makes weird echoing/crackling noises while playing videos or other people's talk from discord etc.
The weird noises stay for some time (usually a few minutes, I think) and then disappear again. Turning the device off and on again can help, but doesn't do so necessarily.
I've never had a problem with connecting the microphone (what other people seem to have).
For other people the kernel seems to be the problem:
https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/i2h847/t14t14s_amdlinux_internal_microphone_works_with/
but since I've got 5.11.0-37-generic I think that shouldn't be the problem?

What else:
I've got ubuntu 20.04.
Here's a recording of the noise: https://voca.ro/114YFb1BAlzo

Thanks in advance!
Winterstorm

Edit:
systemctl --user status pulseaudio gave me

```
● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor >
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-10-15 11:56:30 CEST; 15min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pulseaudio.socket
   Main PID: 1744 (pulseaudio)
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/pulseaudio.service
             └─1744 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal

Okt 15 11:56:30 Nyx systemd[1737]: Starting Sound Service...
Okt 15 11:56:30 Nyx pulseaudio[1744]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedeskt>
Okt 15 11:56:30 Nyx systemd[1737]: Started Sound Service.
```

And for journalctl | grep pulseaudio the terminal kind of exploded and I just take the entries for today and yesterday, since I've had the problem yesterday:

```
Okt 14 08:11:41 Nyx dbus-daemon[964]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service' requested by ':1.27' (uid=125 pid=1111 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 14 08:11:42 Nyx dbus-daemon[964]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.38' (uid=125 pid=1111 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 14 08:12:08 Nyx dbus-daemon[964]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.75' (uid=1000 pid=1758 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 14 08:12:08 Nyx pulseaudio[1758]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found.
    Okt 14 08:12:13 Nyx systemd[1100]: pulseaudio.service: Succeeded.
    Okt 14 08:12:24 Nyx systemd[1100]: pulseaudio.socket: Succeeded.
    Okt 14 10:02:27 Nyx dbus-daemon[964]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service' requested by ':1.153' (uid=1000 pid=1758 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 14 10:02:27 Nyx dbus-daemon[964]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service' requested by ':1.154' (uid=1000 pid=1758 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 14 10:02:27 Nyx dbus-daemon[964]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service' requested by ':1.155' (uid=1000 pid=1758 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 14 10:02:27 Nyx dbus-daemon[964]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service' requested by ':1.156' (uid=1000 pid=1758 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 14 10:02:27 Nyx dbus-daemon[964]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service' requested by ':1.157' (uid=1000 pid=1758 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 14 10:02:27 Nyx pulseaudio[1758]: After module unload, module 'module-null-sink' was still loaded!
    Okt 14 10:02:27 Nyx systemd[1752]: pulseaudio.service: Succeeded.
    Okt 14 10:02:27 Nyx systemd[1752]: pulseaudio.socket: Succeeded.
    Okt 14 17:41:24 Nyx dbus-daemon[982]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service' requested by ':1.27' (uid=125 pid=1130 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 14 17:41:24 Nyx dbus-daemon[982]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.38' (uid=125 pid=1130 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 14 17:41:37 Nyx dbus-daemon[982]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.75' (uid=1000 pid=1777 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 14 17:41:37 Nyx pulseaudio[1777]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found.
    Okt 14 17:41:41 Nyx systemd[1124]: pulseaudio.service: Succeeded.
    Okt 14 17:41:52 Nyx systemd[1124]: pulseaudio.socket: Succeeded.
    Okt 14 23:50:24 Nyx dbus-daemon[982]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service' requested by ':1.218' (uid=1000 pid=1777 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 14 23:50:24 Nyx dbus-daemon[982]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service' requested by ':1.219' (uid=1000 pid=1777 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 14 23:50:24 Nyx dbus-daemon[982]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service' requested by ':1.220' (uid=1000 pid=1777 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 14 23:50:24 Nyx dbus-daemon[982]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service' requested by ':1.221' (uid=1000 pid=1777 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 14 23:50:24 Nyx dbus-daemon[982]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service' requested by ':1.222' (uid=1000 pid=1777 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 14 23:50:24 Nyx pulseaudio[1777]: After module unload, module 'module-null-sink' was still loaded!
    Okt 14 23:50:24 Nyx systemd[1771]: pulseaudio.service: Succeeded.
    Okt 14 23:50:24 Nyx systemd[1771]: pulseaudio.socket: Succeeded.
    Okt 15 11:55:15 Nyx dbus-daemon[931]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service' requested by ':1.28' (uid=125 pid=1345 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 15 11:55:16 Nyx dbus-daemon[931]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.41' (uid=125 pid=1345 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 15 11:55:48 Nyx pulseaudio[1345]: Error opening PCM device hdmi:1,1: No such file or directory
    Okt 15 11:55:48 Nyx pulseaudio[1345]: Error opening PCM device hw:Generic_1: No such device
    Okt 15 11:55:48 Nyx pulseaudio[1345]: Error opening PCM device hw:acp: No such device
    Okt 15 11:55:48 Nyx pulseaudio[1345]: Error opening PCM device hw:Generic_1: No such device
    Okt 15 11:55:48 Nyx systemd[1295]: pulseaudio.service: Succeeded.
    Okt 15 11:55:48 Nyx systemd[1295]: pulseaudio.socket: Succeeded.
    Okt 15 11:56:19 Nyx dbus-daemon[950]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service' requested by ':1.27' (uid=125 pid=1097 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 15 11:56:20 Nyx dbus-daemon[950]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.39' (uid=125 pid=1097 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 15 11:56:30 Nyx dbus-daemon[950]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.76' (uid=1000 pid=1744 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
    Okt 15 11:56:30 Nyx pulseaudio[1744]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found.
    Okt 15 11:56:34 Nyx systemd[1091]: pulseaudio.service: Succeeded.
```

Comment: Since that problem seems to be occur randomly, I'be interested in the output of `systemctl --user status pulseaudio` or `journalctl | grep pulseaudio`. Copy the output of the terminal`s answer and add it to your question using the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1369285/edit) button

Comment: Thanks, did that. Hope it helps. Especially the journalct1 part looks kind of messy. Would you prefer a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry can't see anything. So you might look at the `alsamixer`and make sure that the output gains are not too high (-3 db as a starter)

Comment: Thanks, did that. I'll wait to see if the noises come back.

Comment: Hi, so the noises did come back, but it seems to me they disappear after a shorter time. Can't say for sure though

Comment: Checked that with other hardware? (aka headphones or mics). Cool, that you are still pursuing that problem. Don't give up!

Comment: Yeah, it appears with my headphones as well. 

Thanks, honestly I have to because it is very annoying when I have to study... thanks for helping me!

Comment: Update: So this time around the noises had first only a weird cracking, but then the echo reappeared. 

I tried if it has anything to do with my second monitor; for 2 times out of 3, when the noises appeared and I removed the second monitor, the noises disappeared. This time however they stayed.